# How to fix javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: input must be under 64 bytes in android?

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

I have an android messaging application that connects to a server. The app and server communicate through "packets". These packets are deserialized objects encrypted through [hybrid encryption](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-hybrid-cryptography-example/). For some reason I get the following error when trying to encrypt data:

```
W/System.err: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: input must be under 64 bytes
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipherRSA.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipherRSA.java:245)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1204)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.SealedObject.<init>(SealedObject.java:103)
W/System.err:     at com.baiocchi.enigma.client.util.encryption.EncryptionOutputStream.writeObject(EncryptionOutputStream.java:35)
W/System.err:     at com.baiocchi.enigma.client.util.CredentialInflator.deflateCredentials(CredentialInflator.java:31)
W/System.err:     at com.baiocchi.enigma.shared.packet.Packet.encryptCredentials(Packet.java:55)
W/System.err:     at com.baiocchi.enigma.client.util.handlers.PacketDeflationHandler.run(PacketDeflationHandler.java:34)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I am out of ideas and have foudn no answers online. Please help!
Here are the methods used:

Encryptor:

```
public class Encryptor {


    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, RSAKey asymmetricKey) {
        if (asymmetricKey instanceof RSAPublicKey) {
            return encrypt(data, (RSAPublicKey) asymmetricKey);
        }
        return encrypt(data, (RSAPrivateKey) asymmetricKey);
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, RSAPublicKey asymmetricKey) {
        try {
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Config.ASYMMETRIC_TRANSFORMATION);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, asymmetricKey);
            return cipher.doFinal(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, RSAPrivateKey asymmetricKey) {
        try {
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Config.ASYMMETRIC_TRANSFORMATION);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, asymmetricKey);
            return cipher.doFinal(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

EncryptionOutputStream:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SealedObject;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class EncryptionOutputStream extends ByteArrayOutputStream {
    private final Cipher cipher;

    public EncryptionOutputStream(SymmetricEncryptionKey symmetricEncryptionKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        super();
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Config.SYMMETRIC_TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, symmetricEncryptionKey.getKey(), new IvParameterSpec(symmetricEncryptionKey.getIvParameter()));
    }

    public void writeObject(Serializable object) throws IOException {
        try {
            final SealedObject sealedObject = new SealedObject(object, cipher);
            final ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(this);
            outputStream.writeObject(sealedObject);
        } catch (final IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Packet encrypt method:

```
public final void encryptCredentials(RSAKey asymmetricKey) throws IOException {
    if (credentials != null) {
        SymmetricEncryptionKey symmetricEncryptionKey = EncryptionKeyGenerator.createNewSymmetricKey().getSymmetricEncryptionKey();
        encryptedCredentials = CredentialInflator.deflateCredentials(symmetricEncryptionKey, credentials);
        credentials = null;
        encryptedKey = Encryptor.encrypt(symmetricEncryptionKey.getKey().getEncoded(), asymmetricKey);
        encryptedIvParameter = Encryptor.encrypt(symmetricEncryptionKey.getIvParameter(), asymmetricKey);
    }
}
```

Credential encrypt method:

```
 public static byte[] deflateCredentials(SymmetricEncryptionKey key, Credentials credentials) throws IOException {
    try (EncryptionOutputStream outStream = new EncryptionOutputStream(key)) {
        outStream.writeObject(credentials);
        return outStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

SymmetricEncryptionKey Class:

```
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
public class SymmetricEncryptionKey {

private final SecretKey key;
private byte[] ivParameter = new byte[16];

public SymmetricEncryptionKey(SecretKey key, byte[] ivParameter) {
    this.key = key;
    this.ivParameter = ivParameter;
}

public SecretKey getKey() {
    return key;
}

public byte[] getIvParameter() {
    return ivParameter;
}}
```

Comment: The exception doesn't quite track the code you posted. But you have left out critical details, like the values of the constants in the Config class. Ideally you should post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we could just run the code ourselves and see the same error as you.

Answer (score 1):

The final block of the data must be 64 bytes or less (which can include 0 bytes).  That's because the algorithm works on 64 byte blocks, and it needs to pad the data appropriately in the last block.  If you have 64 or more bytes left, you shouldn't be doing the final block you should be encrypting the next 64 bytes as non-final.

If you don't know that, you haven't studied encryption much.  I'd consider not doing this and tunneling your connection over SSL instead.  Encryption is easy for even experts to get wrong.  For example, how are you doing key exchange?  Better to use a tested library/solution than to roll anything on your own.